# Select font for buffer via [Gtk] GUI font selection tool

Tags: faces, fonts, buffer-local

From the menu-bar selecting:  Option -> Set Default Font...
pops up a (Gtk?) font selection tool:
[image]

Is there a nice way to select font for the *current (or specific) buffer*
without configuration saving, via similar tool ?